# Beeping on startup and keyboard light stays on

Tags: windows, runtime-error, autostart

When I startup my pc (which I recently built), it sometimes gives a few beeps and proceeds to start up. Is this a bad sign or can anyone tell me more about this?

Also I have a led keyboard which shuts down like it should except for one light which is quite bright, can anyone tell me why this happens and how to fix it?
The keyboard I am speaking about is the sharkoon skiller pro.

Comment: I suggest asking the keyboard question in a separate question, and Edit it out of this question.  Please include the make and model of the keyboard.

Comment: *and proceeds to start up*...Please clarify what you mean by this. Does the system start normally? Something else?

Comment: Yes the system proceeds to start normally.

Answer (score 1):

Find out the make and model, like Dell Precision T1500.  Google for its manual, and look up "POST codes" or "startup beeps".  Most likely, you have one bad component (like a bad RAM stick).  You will have to troubleshoot those issues individually.

Comment: It isnt a pre build pc. I have built it myself.. so I assume to perhaps check a motherboard manual?

Comment: Precisely, check the motherboard manual.